# Click works when the page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need help, `click` works immediately when the page loads. I read and tried different options, but it does not help. I can not find the right solution.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '/print',
        success: function (response) {

            function printContent(el) {
                var restorepage = document.body.innerHTML;
                var printcontent = document.getElementById(el).innerHTML;
                document.body.innerHTML = printcontent;
                window.print();
                document.body.innerHTML = restorepage;
            }

            response.forEach(function (element, index) {
                $('div.h4').after(
                    '<div id="print_' + index + '">' +
                    '<p>' + element + '</p>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<button id="button_' + index + '">Print</button>'
                );

                var el = document.getElementById('button_' + index);
                el.addEventListener('click', printContent('print_' + index), false);
            })
        }
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="h4"></div>
```

Comment: Please share your HTML code as well so the people can know whats wrong

Comment: It helped you to understand what the problem is?

Comment: Can you post, what 'response' is?

Comment: response is plain text

Comment: `printContent('print_'+index)` is *calling* the function immediately. Use `function() {printContent('print_'+index);}` instead.

Comment: Niet the Dark Absol, thanks, it works!

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is on `el.addEventListener('click', printContent('print_' + index), false);` you are immediately calling the function instead replace above mentioned line as below

`el.addEventListener('click', printContent, false);`

and change your `printContent` function as below

```
function printContent() {
   var el = $(this).prev().attr('id');
   var restorepage = document.body.innerHTML;
   var printcontent = document.getElementById(el).innerHTML;
   document.body.innerHTML = printcontent;
   window.print();
   document.body.innerHTML = restorepage;
}
```

I haven't tested it but it should work. Please let me know if it does not work.